# USB to serial adapter for full duplex communication

Tags: linux, serial-port, usb, usbserial

I have a modem with a serial port but my PC does not have a serial port. Hence, I bought an adapter like below picture. Once the modem switch to transmit mode, it can send something but it could never switch back to receive mode and its data light goes red. Does such an adapter may cause this failure? I am not familiar with these communication things such as full duplex etc.

[image]

Comment: You'll get more information search with this device number regarding modem compatibility on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your issue is not an adapter itself, but software settings.

It is very important to properly set settings like speed, parity, flow control, etc.

On Linux, probably easiest way to check on these is to use `minicom`.

Most serial port devices max out at 115200 bps (however there are some USB/serial ports that support speeds as high as 2 mbps).

Most serial devices use `8` bits per byte, `n`o parity, and use `1` stop but (aka `8N1`).

And finally, one important setting is flow control. Best and very often supported is hardware flow control (aka `RTS/CTS`). Some devices do not support RTS/CTS, but support software flow control, aka `XON/XOFF`. It is typically bad idea to not use any flow control.

For your modem, you should try running `minicom -D /dev/ttyUSBn` (where `n` is your device number, most likely `0`), get to configuration mode using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd> and use following settings: speed `115200`, `8N1` (8 bits/byte, no parity, 1 stop bit), `RTS/CTS` (hw flow control, preferable) or `XON/XOFF` (sw flow control).

You can also use Linux utility `stty` to set these parameters on port by default, but since your device is USB, these settings will be lost as soon as USB device is disconnected - so it is better to have your modem program know how to configure these settings without external helpers.